# How to Have 2nd Step Verification for Making Calls in 6.0?

Tags: security, 6.0-marshmallow

I would like to use 2nd Step Verification always for Making Calls. I can use a second device to get those codes; etc second Gmail account; or a similar encryption device as used by banks. I do not want to use the same device to get the code and call. 
The current layer of protection is not enough in Android 6.0 System.

- Problem: anyone who has access to your phone can make a call. This is a serious problem. Reasons and logs about them, I have provided private to developers of bottle necks.
- Motivation of crackers in end-to-end. If the cracker can get through the protection layers, they can kill end-to-end applications for some reason. Experienced compromises in Signal.

---

How can you Have 2nd Step Verification for Making Calls in 6.0?

Comment: This is all theoretical but seems doable: there are  command-line ways to generate time based one time password (totp; requires a key). This same password can be generated by Google Authenticator on an another device as well (requires the same key). You can setup Tasker to create an overlay when the call comes in and lets you attend only when you enter the correct totp.

Comment: @Firelord It would be great to have Tasker independent system for security.